# Candy Crush keeps closing itself on new tablet

Tags: technical-issues, candy-crush-saga

I've been playing candy crush on my iPhone and laptop via facebook. I recently bought a new versus tablet and downloaded candy crush via play.com, however when I open the game it chucks me out after a few seconds. The same thing happens when I open it in Facebook. The game plays fine on my iPhone and laptop so it seems to be the tablet. Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Comment: Any error messages?  Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: No error messages and uninstalled and reinstalled four times.

Comment: After my sixth attempt at uninstalling and reinstalling I have a success. Thanks for taking the time to reply David Starkey.